# How to Choose Poisson Time Interval

Tags: poisson-distribution, discrete-data, poisson-process

A Poisson process is one where mean = var = λ. How do you decide what time interval fulfills these criteria when fitting the Poisson distribution to a process? Can all processes be modeled as Poisson with a specific time interval?

If we find an interval that satisfies those requirements, is it valid to scale the lambda parameter up to fit a more natural time interval? Suppose a process is Poisson when T1 = 0.43 sec, but we want to transform the distribution s.t. T2 = 1 minute, where T is the time interval. If the distribution parameter for T1 is λ1, and the parameter for T2 is λ2, would λ2 = (T2/T1) * λ1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Suppose $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 10)$ for 15-minute time
periods. Then the rate $\lambda$ would be $\lambda = 4(10) = 40$
for one-hour (60-min.) time periods.

Consider averages of $n=1000$ observations from each:

```
set.seed(1023)
x.15 = rpois(1000, 10)
summary(x.15);  var(x.15)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    8.00   10.00   10.03   12.00   23.00 
[1] 10.52243
```

Sample mean and variance are both approximately $\lambda=10.$

```
x.60 = rpois(1000, 40)
summary(x.60);  var(x.60)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  21.00   36.00   40.00   40.13   44.00   60.00 
[1] 40.37895
```

Sample mean and variance are both approximately $\lambda = 40.$

Furthermore, if we take sums of results for four disjoint 15-minute time periods, we get results similar to those for one-hour time periods. In particular, sums have mean and variance about $40.$

```
set.seed(2020) 
s = replicate( 1000, sum(rpois(4, 10)) )     
summary(s);  var(s)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  22.00   36.00   40.00   39.98   44.00   66.00 
[1] 42.13966
```

Histograms for `x.60` and `s`. Centers of open circles show exact Poisson probabilities.

[image]

R code for figure:

```
cp = seq(-.5, 66.6)
k = 0:66;  pdf = dpois(k, 40)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
 hdr1 = "Counts Per Hour Period"
 hist(x.60, prob=T, br=cp, col="skyblue2", main=hdr1)
  points(k, pdf, col="red")
 hdr2 = "Total in Four 15-Min Periods"
 hist(s, prob=T, br=cp, col="skyblue2", main=hdr2)
  points(k, pdf, col="red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: Great answer, I appreciate the illustration. I have a follow-up regarding my motivation for asking this question. My question comes from a dataset I am trying to identify the time interval and lambda for. In this dataset, mean(events) == var(events) on an unnatural time interval (0.000234s), but this is not the case on a larger time interval (1s). Instead, mean(events) << var(events). If this is the case, can we still use the additive property of the Poisson parameter as you have shown? If so, why, or why not?